# Conditionally rendering contents of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, frontend

I am making a memory game, [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly4rzzvjyl), and I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. Get the cards to be dealt initially face down (icon hidden so to speak)
2. onClick, the icon on the card that is clicked is revealed, none of the others is revealed
3. When the second card is clicked that icon is revealed, if they match the cards are removed anyway (that part works) but if they don't, the icons are hidden again.

I tried adding a "buttonMask" class in the parent div but it overrides my existing class. I tried display: none in the parent div also, no luck.

Other attempts included adding a state property to the Card.js component this.state.isHidden: true and trying to toggle the visibility. I read the docs, [This](https://blog.logrocket.com/conditional-rendering-in-react-c6b0e5af381e), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876244/best-way-to-conditional-render-react-components-and-keep-it-dry), and [eddyerburgh](https://eddyerburgh.me/toggle-visibility-with-react). I'm stuck on this condition render, everything else works great, this piece got me

This is my conditional for dealing the cards

```
class Cards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const card = (
      <div style={sty}>
        {this.props.cardTypes ? (
          this.props.cardTypes.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <button style={cardStyle} value={item} key={index}>
                {" "}
                {item}{" "}
              </button>
           );
         })
        ) : (
          <div> No Cards </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
    return <Card card={card} removeMatches={this.props.removeMatches} 
   />;
 }
```

Originally, when I first tried this, I was passing state to all the cards, not just individual cards, that was why I was not able to toggle them individually.

This was the original render in Cards.js

```
if (this.state.hidden) {
    return (
      <button
        key={card + index}
        style={btn}
        onClick={this.revealIcon}
        id={card}
      >
        <div style={btnMask}>{card}</div>
      </button>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <button
        key={card + index}
        style={btn}
        onClick={this.revealIcon}
        id={card}
      >
        <div>{card}</div>
      </button>
    );
  }
```

Comment: dont just link code sandbox put code here and isolate the problem

Comment: I was trying to be brief, I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally render an element with an inline if with logical &&:

```
return(
  <div>
    {this.props.shouldRenderTheThing && 
    <span>Conditionally rendered span</span>}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: So what the code means is that I render empty buttons first with __this.state.isHidden: true__ and then if call the toggle function in my removeMatch function I'll output just one card with an icon?

Comment: I do not know, I looked at your code and it was not easy to follow. The example I pasted shows how to conditionally include an element in the rendering based on a boolean prop. If you paste a react component that shows your rendering logic for the cards, it will be easier to give you guidance on how to conditionally render specific cards.

Comment: Chris, I don't have rendering logic, my attempts fail. The conditional render that I posted is for the type of cards dealt, easy or hard. The second code snippet was my attempt at conditionally rendering a  visible or hidden card which only worked for all cards not just one individually.

Comment: Again, your code is confusing. You have a class called Cards that returns a <Card> element that includes as its props an array of buttons that represent cards. It would make more logical sense if your Cards class was returning a <div> with <Card> elements representing each card, then the Card class would render a single card. However, as I re-read your post and your comments, it is also not clear what is not working. You list three goals above, and in the last one you say "that part works".

Comment: Chris that is why I intially didn't add the code in question. I linked to the Codesandbox which provides a better context for what I'm trying to accomplish, I think the code above does in fact confuse the issue, but as Omar pointed out, that isn't SO etiquette. From the beginning, what can I provide to give you more clarification?

Comment: A simple description of the problem along with sample code showing what you've tried that is not working. I would strongly suggest creating a sample that only tries to solve the problem, not something tied up in the rest of your code. For example, create two simple classes, Cards and Card. Prove that they work properly. Then add a prop that allows a card to be conditionally not rendered. If that does not work, then you can paste the simple example and get that problem solved outside of the complexity of your card game.

Comment: Chris, this is what is what I have so far [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7q02x5pym), first question is how do I render the correct number of 'blank buttons' (buttons that do not show icons)? The correct number is the same amount as if I mapped over the state array in the first place.  I conditionally rendered one button if state is toggled.

Comment: I see that you render a single button that when clicked enables all cards to render as divs. This does not make sense to me in terms of what you are looking for. I don't know what you mean by "mapped over the state array". Your state is an object with contains an isHidden property and an array of cards. What part of the state are you expecting to indicate which cards should be blank?

Comment: I render a single button, because that's all I know how to do right now. In the original question I am trying to render buttons that show no icons, when a single button is clicked the card/button shows the icon only on that particular button.

Comment: I honestly do not know what you're trying to do. I hacked your sample to show blank cards and then reveal when clicked, then blank when clicked again. One confusing thing is that you have one property for visibility but it sounds like you are wanting to keep track of this for individual cards, so I changed the array to be objects that include their visibility and their value. https://codesandbox.io/s/p2jr3v7vx0

Comment: OK, now I am able to render multiple blank buttons. On to question two. How can I individually toggle buttons? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7q02x5pym)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169045/discussion-between-kevin-t-and-chris-edgington).